# SQL Server Stored Procedure to Combine Output results from 2 OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This is my first post. Hoping to get some help with my code.

I am attempting to write a stored procedure to combine results from 2 open queries each pointing to different linked server.

Stored procedure accepts one parameter.

The first `OPENQUERY` returns multiple rows of `Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4`

I want to pass results of `Col1` to the second `OPENQUERY` which returns `Col1,Col5,Col6` and then combine the results into a table variable to read from.

I cannot paste exact queries here, but will paste the structure. Hope that helps to understand my current approach. Appreciate if I can get some advice.

This works for 1 input but obviously fails when I pass multiple inputs. How can I handle results of 1st query and pass into 2nd.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProc] 
    @Input AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
        SET NOCOUNT ON;

        DECLARE @TSQL1 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @TSQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        DECLARE @Col1Results NVARCHAR(MAX)

        /*** OpenQuery 1***/
        SELECT  @TSQL1 = 'SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4 FROM Table1
                          WHERE Input IN ('''+ @Input +''') '

        DECLARE @tblTempTable1 AS TABLE 
                                  (
                                      Col1 NVARCHAR(100),
                                      Col2 NVARCHAR(100),
                                      Col3 NVARCHAR(50),
                                      Col4 NVARCHAR(50)
                                  )

        INSERT INTO @tblTempTable1 
            EXEC (@TSQL1) AT [LinkedServer1]

        SELECT @Col1Results = Col1 
        FROM @tblTempTable1 

        /*** Open Query 2***/
        SELECT  @TSQL2 = 'SELECT Col1, Col5, Col6 FROM Table2
                          WHERE Input IN ('''+ @Col1Results +''') '

        DECLARE @tblTempTable2 AS TABLE 
                                  (
                                       Col1 NVARCHAR(100),
                                       Col5 NVARCHAR(100),
                                       Col6 NVARCHAR(50)
                                  )

        INSERT INTO @tblTempTable2 
            EXEC (@TSQL2) AT [LinkedServer2]

        SELECT 
            t1.Col1, t1.Col2, t1.Col3, t2.Col2, t2.Col3
        FROM
            @tblTempTable1 t1
        INNER JOIN
            @tblTempTable2 t2 ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
    END CATCH
```

`---------------------------Update---------------------------------`
I was able to use Cursor to achieve the desired outcome. But Noticed that using cursor hit performance to great extent. Can the below code be optimised further to increase performance. Thanks.

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProc] 
    @Input AS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
    BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


Declare @tblTempTable1 Table
            (
                Col1 Nvarchar(100),
                Col2 Nvarchar(100),
                Col3 nvarchar(50),
                Col4 nvarchar(50)
            )

SELECT  @TSQL1 = 'Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 From Table1
              where Input in ('''+@Input+''')'

Insert @tblTempTable1 EXEC (@TSQL1) at [LinkedServer1]

Declare @tblTempTable2 Table
            (
                Col1 Nvarchar(100),
            Col2 Nvarchar(100),
                Col3 nvarchar(50)
        )

Declare db_cursor CURSOR for 
Select Col1 from @tblTempVTErrors

Open db_cursor
fetch NEXT FROM db_cursor into @Column1

While @@FETCH_STATUS=0
Begin


SELECT  @TSQL2 = 'Select Col1,Col5,Col6 From Table2
              where Col1 in ('''+@Column1+''')'

Insert @tblTempTable2 EXEC (@TSQL2) at [LinkedServer2]

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @Column1


End

Close db_Cursor
Deallocate db_Cursor


    Select t1.Col1,t1.Col2,t1.Col3,t2.Col2,t2.Col3
    from @tblTempTable1 t1
    inner join @tblTempTable2 t2 on t1.Col1=t2.Col1

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: can you share some examples regarding this part :`This works for 1 Input but obviously fails when i pass multiple inputs`

Comment: Are we to understand that Input is a unique identifier?

Comment: Thanks for looking into my problem. I am calling this Stored Procedure from an excel Report using VBA. Originally, the 2 Open Queries were 2 separate stored procedures and they worked fine. Now I am trying to combine the Output in a single report. I am passing comma separated inputs from Excel Like Input1,Input2, Input3...  Hope this helps

Comment: Just to add further, If I pass Input 1 and run the procedure, I get all the columns returned by last Select query. But if I pass Input1, Input 2, it fails. Guess I am handling the results incorrectly at this part... Select @Col1Results= Col1 from @tblTempTable1

Comment: If you need to pass in multiple values via a parameter, look into the **table-valued parameter** feature available in SQL Server **2008** and newer. This would allow you to avoid the dynamic SQL and make things a lot easier....

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, when Input is a single value, say 'Test' then it works, because only one record is selected - Input being some sort of unique identifier.  But as soon as you pass 'Test','Test2','Test3' it fails because it puts multiple records into @tblTempTable1, and then the SELECT @Col1Results will fail because more than one record is selected?

If so, then you need to do something like this:

Create a function to allow you to split this sort of input parameter.  I use:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplit](
    @sInputList VARCHAR(max) -- List of delimited items
  , @sDelimiter VARCHAR(5) -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (item VARCHAR(max))

BEGIN
DECLARE @sItem VARCHAR(max)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0) <> 0
 BEGIN
 SELECT
  @sItem=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,1,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)-1))),
  @sInputList=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@sInputList,CHARINDEX(@sDelimiter,@sInputList,0)+LEN(@sDelimiter),LEN(@sInputList))))

 IF LEN(@sItem) > 0
  INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sItem
 END

IF LEN(@sInputList) > 0
 INSERT INTO @List SELECT @sInputList -- Put the last item in
RETURN
END
```

Now you can get rid of all the dynamic SQL and change the procedure simply as:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE MyStoredProc @Input as NVARCHAR(Max)
AS
    BEGIN TRY
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    Declare @tblTempTable1 Table
    (
    Col1 Nvarchar(100),
    Col2 Nvarchar(100),
    Col3 nvarchar(50),
    Col4 nvarchar(50)

    )

    insert INTO @tblTempTable1 
    Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4 From Table1
    where Input in (SELECT Item FROM dbo.fnSplit(@Input, ','))

    Declare @tblTempTable2 Table
    (
    Col1 Nvarchar(100),
    Col2 Nvarchar(100),
    Col3 nvarchar(50)
    )

    insert INTO @tblTempTable2
    Select Col1,Col5,Col6 From Table2
    where Input in (SELECT Col1 FROM @tblTempTable1)

    Select t1.Col1,t1.Col2,t1.Col3,t2.Col2,t2.Col3
    from @tblTempTable1 t1
    inner join @tblTempTable2 t2 on t1.Col1=t2.Col1
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Comment: Could you edit your query to include how will it look when using Linked Servers. I tried few times, but may be using wrong syntax.  The queries I use are not to SQL server but to external system using Linked server, as I use in my code above.

Comment: Normal syntax for linked server is SELECT ... FROM <server>.<database>.<schema>.<table>.  eg DatabaseServer1.db1.dbo.table1